# Windows 10 - Route Certain Traffic Through Specific Interfaces

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, routing

Living in Japan, I have a nifty little router that sits between my modem and my actual routing hardware.  One port is a Japan IP, one port is a US IP.  I have them each hooked up to separate WiFi routers so I can switch to (for example) my US WLAN to watch Hulu.  Which is fine for my phone.

On my PC, however, it is connected to the JP router via Ethernet.  It would be nice if I could also connect to the US WLAN, and then somehow configure things so that (for example) YouTube traffic goes to the WLAN, but Usenet traffic goes to the Ethernet.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'll do:

Have a Wifi receiver USB installed in your USB port (normally it's plug and play) and have it automatically connected to your US WLAN and nothing else. You can then optinally disable the wifi USB via Network Connection.

Now, everytime you want to use US connection, just disable the LAN connection or unplug the cable, whichever gives less hassle to you. If you need your Japan connection, disable the wifi and enable the LAN.

This might not fully addresses what you want: automatically routes specific domain to specific router, but this is **the most simple** and anyone with basic computer skill can do it.

This is the setup I currently use on my PC: ethernet, and tethering via my phone, in case someone is downloading large files or watching Youtube.

Comment: I can disable interfaces already, but that's not what I want. I want traffic through my JP interface to continue uninterrupted while certain other traffic preferentially routes through the US interface.

Comment: I didn't come to superuser because I wanted a simple answer. ;)